# No se actualiza un registro en Android Studio y MySQL

Tags: mysql, android-studio, webservice, actualizacion

Muy buenas tardes tengan comunidad, en el desarrollo de mi aplicación mediante Android Studio y el manejo de Web Services de PHP. Tengo 2 tablas creadas y en una de ellas se obtiene mediante el uso de foreign key la matricula de la tabla usuarios. Y aunque todo parece ir normal con el método de la actualización en Android Studio, la verdad es que no se ven reflejados los cambios en mi base de datos.

> Fotos de la estructura de las tablas

[image: Tabla: Usuarios]

[image: Tabla: Centro de costos]

> Archivo "config.php"

```
<?php

$servername = '...';
$dbname = '...';
$username = '...';
$password = '...';

// Creas la conexión
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Checkeas la conexión
if ($con->connect_error) {
  die("Error en la conexión: " . $con->connect_error);
}
//echo "OK";
?>
```

> Archivo "actualizar.php"

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$division = $_POST['division'];
$area = $_POST['area'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];

$act = "UPDATE centrodecostos SET division = '$division', area = '$area' WHERE numero = '$numero'";
if ($con->query($act) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}
?>
```

> Método para "actualizar"

```
private void actualizar(String URL){
// Obtenemos la información de los editText y se convierte a String
String division = eTDivision.getText().toString();
String area = eTArea.getText().toString();
if(division.isEmpty() || area.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes dejar campos vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    StringRequest stringR = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El registro fue actualizado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("division", division);
            parametros.put("area", area);
            Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(parametros));
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue rQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rQ.add(stringR);
}
```

Nota: Todo mi proyecto esta montado en 000webhost, por eso no dejo las credenciales en el archivo config.

Comment: ¿Por qué en tu `query update` recibes un parámetro *número* que en tu método no envías? Otra cosa, tu `response` te devuelve lo que imprime tu `echo`, tú le estás diciendo que independientemente de lo que imprima debe mostrar un `toast` diciendo que se ha actualizado. Te recomiendo que recomiendo que cambies tu `echo` por *1* si es `true` y por *2* si es `false`. En tu `response` pon un `if(response.contains("1")) { toast updated } else { Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, LENGTH_LONG).show();` con eso sabremos cual es el error

Comment: Cuando se tenga un problema es importante revisar si se muestra algún mensaje de error, de lo contrario pueden ser muchas las razones por lo cual no funciona correctamente.

Comment: @Franqo Balsamo: El parámetro "numero", lo utilizo para hacer una consulta en mi base de datos. Además de que es el parámetro con el que se debe de actualizar el registro para eso tengo esto WHERE numero = '$numero'

Comment: @Jorgesys: Voy a seguir las recomendaciones de Franqo para entender que error es.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que en tu método envías dos parámetros a tu archivo php, division y área pero no le envías el parámetro número. @VictorManuel

Comment: Tu observación del parámetro fue la respuesta a mi problema, cuando en el PHP paso el parámetro por el método POST, de igual forma se lo paso en AD ya que es el que comprueba cual registro debe ser eliminado.